# UIActivityViewController show in different language

Tags: ios, objective-c

i want to remove or translate 'more' from english to russian.

[image]

Controller initiated simply as follows:

```
  UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:objectsToShare applicationActivities:@[fbAct, vk2Act, okAct, twAct, gpAct, mailAct]];

        [self presentViewController:activityVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't hide or remove more button according to apple policy

It comes as the default language of iPhone

If u need to change that you can use custom library https://github.com/overshare/overshare-kit

Comment: But my default language is Russian, why am i see english?

Comment: iphone region is also russia ??

Comment: i guess not. How should i change it?

Comment: In setting--> general --> language & region-->change region format

Comment: I already did (in plist), setted Localization native development region to ru, but nothing changed ((